# Highcharts.map depreciated warning

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have recently been getting the following warning message indicating that Highcharts.map is depreciated

**Highcharts warning: Deprecated member - Highcharts.map: use Array.map**

I am using the current Highcharts codeline (from https://code.highcharts.com)

However I cannot find any indication or examples as to how to replace Highcharts.map with Array.map.

Annoyingly the Highcharts demo (from the official Highcharts website) still shows the use of Highcharts.map and displays the same message about depreciation.

The offending call is in my plotOptions:

```
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return bardynamicdatalabel.call(this);
                    }
                },
                colors: Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
                    return {
                        linearGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.5, r: 0.7 },
                        stops: [
                            [0.6,new Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')], // darken
                            [1, color]
                            
                        ]
                    };
                })
            },
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: _"how to replace Highcharts.map with Array.map"_ - Read the [documentation for `Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and you should be able to solve this warning.

Comment: I have looked at your suggestion and I am none the wiser. I can read the document but cannot transpose the information into a solution.

Comment: `Highcharts.map()` expects an array and a function. `Array.map()` is called on an array and expects a function. Obviously `HIghcharts.getOptions().colors` has to be an array, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Highcharts.map` and `Array.map` are similar and it is very easy to convert one into another, example:

```
    colors: Highcharts.getOptions().colors.map(function(color) {
        return {
            linearGradient: {
                cx: 0.5,
                cy: 0.5,
                r: 0.7
            },
            stops: [
                [0.6, new Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')], // darken
                [1, color]
            ]
        };
    })
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/krm2evc7/

Comment: awsesomeness thanks man